# Why can't I record from RemoteIOUnit after changing AudioSession category from SoloAmbient to PlayAndRecord?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, avaudiosession

My app has both audio play and record features, and I want to only set the audio session's category to `PlayAndRecord` when the user initiates recording, so the standard audio playback will be muted by the mute switch, etc.

I'm having a problem though, where my call to `AudioUnitRender` to record audio input is failing with `errParam` (-50) after I change the audio session category to `PlayAndRecord`. If I start my app using the `PlayAndRecord` category, then recording works correctly.

```
@implementation MyAudioSession
- (instancetype)init {
  NSError *error = nil;
  AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient];
  [session setActive:YES error:&error];
}

- (void)enableRecording {
  void (^setCategory)(void) = ^{
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
  };
  // Do I need to set the category from the main thread?
  if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    setCategory();
  } else {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      setCategory();
    });
  }
}
@end

@interface MyRecorder {
  AudioUnit ioUnit_;
  AudioBufferList *tmpRecordListPtr_
@end

@implementation MyRecorder
- (instancetype)init {
  // Sets up AUGraph with just a RemoteIOUnit node, recording enabled, callback, etc.
  // Set up audio buffers
  tmpRecordListPtr_ = malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + 64 * sizeof(AudioBuffer));
}

- (OSStatus)doRecordCallback:(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *)ioActionFlags
                   timeStamp:(AudioTimeStamp *)inTimeStamp
                   busNumber:(UInt32)busNumber
                   numFrames:(UInt32)numFrames
                   bufferOut:(AudioBufferList *)ioData {
  // Set up buffers... All this works fine if I initialize the audio session to
  // PlayAndRecord in -[MyAudioSession init]
  OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(ioUnit_, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, busNumber,
                                    numFrames, tmpRecordListPtr_);
  // This fails with errParam, but only if I start my app in SoloAmbient and then
  // later change it to PlayAndRecord
}
@end

OSStatus MyRecorderCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                            AudioTimeStamp *inTimestamp, UInt32 inBusNumber,
                            UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData) {
  MyRecorder *recorder = (MyRecorder *)inRefCon;
  return [recorder doRecordCallback:ioActionFlags
                          timeStamp:inTimestamp
                          busNumber:inBusNumber
                          numFrames:inNumberFrames
                          bufferOut:ioData];
}
```

I'm testing on an iPod touch (5th gen) running iOS 7.1.2.

Has anybody else encountered this issue? Any suggestions for fixes or more info I can post?

**EDIT**: Object lifecycle is similar to:

```
- (void)startRecording {
  [mySession enableRecording];
  [myRecorder release];
  myRecorder = [[MyRecorder alloc] init];
  [myRecorder start]; // starts the AUGraph
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code it is difficult to comment. But I am doing something similar in my app, and I found that it is important to pay careful attention to what audio session settings can be changed only when the audio session is inactive.

```
// Get the app's audioSession singleton object
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

//error handling
NSError* audioSessionError = nil;

SDR_DEBUGPRINT(("Setting session not active!\n"));
[session setActive:NO error:&audioSessionError]; // shut down the audio session if it is active
```

It is important to setActive to "NO" prior to changing the session category, for instance. Failure to do so might allow render callbacks to occur while the session is being configured.

Looking at the lifecycle flow, I'm trying to see where you stop the AUGraph prior to setting up the audio session for recording. The code I use for stopping the AUGraph follows. I call it prior to any attempts to reconfigure the audio session.

```
- (void)stopAUGraph {
if(mAudioGraph != nil)  {
    Boolean isRunning = FALSE;

    OSStatus result = AUGraphIsRunning(mAudioGraph, &isRunning);
    if(result) {
        DEBUGPRINT(("AUGraphIsRunning result %d %08X %4.4s\n", (int)result, (int)result, (char*)&result));
        return;
    }

    if(isRunning) {
        result = AUGraphStop(mAudioGraph);

        if(result) {
            DEBUGPRINT(("AUGraphStop result %d %08X %4.4s\n", (int)result, (int)result, (char*)&result));
            return;
        } else {
            DEBUGPRINT(("mAudioGraph has been stopped!\n"));
        }
    } else {
        DEBUGPRINT(("mAudioGraph is already stopped!\n"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `-setActive:` is documented to be alright to call while the audio session is active, although it then fires a route change notification. In any case, deactivating my session before changing the category did not help. I'll try posting the code that seems relevant. I'm pretty new to this code base though, so I may miss something.

Comment: I think it is probably necessary that you ensure that no render callbacks occur while the audio session is being reconfigured. I actually dispose of the remoteIO unit and create a new one each time the session is reconfigured. But it might be sufficient to disable callbacks and reconfigure the existing instance of the unit.

Comment: I'm already disposing of and recreating the recorder graph after reconfiguring the session for recording. I've added some pseudocode showing what the recorder object lifecycle is like to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the RemoteIO Audio Unit (the audio graph) is stopped before deactivating and/or changing the audio session type.  Then (re)initialize the RemoteIO Audio Unit after setting the new session type and before (re)starting the graph, as the new session type or options may change some of the allowable settings.  Also, it helps to check all the prior audio unit and audio session call error codes before any graph (re)start.

Comment: The audio graph is not running when I change the session category, and I have tried rebuilding the graph after changing the category. I just got it working by re-setting the preferred sample rate and IO buffer duration after changing the category, but now the code is kind of a mess. Once I figure out what exactly made the difference and clean up my code, I'll post what I find out.

Comment: The RemoteIO sample rate and buffer duration may need to get reconfigured to match how the RemoteIO unit is allowed to connect to the OS under any new audio session type.

Comment: Just as additional confirmation of what you've found, I do set those parameters in the remoteIO in my app each time I create it - and I have no problem with changing audio session categories.

Comment: It looks like the issue was with the buffer duration. We set a custom IO buffer duration on the session when it is initialized, and changing the category seems to be resetting the IO buffer duration. When I set the IO buffer duration after changing the category, everything works correctly.